# Agora Broadcast live streaming black screen on ios browsers when starting a stream agora-rtc-sdk-ng react web app

Tags: video-streaming, broadcastreceiver, streaming, broadcast, live

I'm working on a react web app , where users can start broadcast live streaming for their audiences.
I'm using agora-rtc-sdk-ng version : 4.17.2 for that
when i start a live on my computer browser or an android phone browser the live is working correctly as expected but when i switch to an iOS browser and start a live i got a black screen and the live is not started even if I'm authorizing the app to use the camera and microphone
this is the code I'm using for my provider

```
import React, {createContext, useContext, useEffect, useMemo, useState} from "react";
import AgoraRTC, { ClientConfig, IAgoraRTCClient } from "agora-rtc-sdk-ng";
import { AGORA_APP_ID } from "./config";

type AppConfiguration = {
  agoraAppId: string,
  agoraEnable: boolean
};

type AgoraRTCProviderState = {
  client: IAgoraRTCClient | null,
  appConfiguration: AppConfiguration | null,
  config: ClientConfig | null
};

const AgoraContext = createContext<AgoraRTCProviderState>({ client: null, appConfiguration: null, config: null });

type props = {
  children: React.ReactNode,
  config: ClientConfig
};

export const AgoraProvider: React.FC<props> = ({ config, children}) => {
  const [client, setClient] = useState<IAgoraRTCClient | null>(null);
  const [appConfiguration, setAppConfiguration] = useState<AppConfiguration | null>(null);

  const onbeforeunload = () => {
    if (client) {
      client.removeAllListeners();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (AGORA_APP_ID)
      setAppConfiguration({
        agoraAppId: AGORA_APP_ID,
        agoraEnable: true
      });

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onbeforeunload);

    const _client = AgoraRTC.createClient(config);
    AgoraRTC.setLogLevel(0);
    if (_client)
      setClient(_client);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", onbeforeunload);
    }
  }, [])

  const value = useMemo(
    () => ({ client, appConfiguration, config}),
    [client, appConfiguration, config]
  );

  return React.createElement(AgoraContext.Provider, { value }, children);
};

AgoraProvider.displayName = 'AgoraProvider';

export const useAgora = () => useContext(AgoraContext);

export default AgoraProvider;
```

this is the provider calling

```
...
<AgoraProvider config={{ mode: "live", codec: "h264", role: "host" }}>
      <Layout>
          <LivePubCom onStatusChanged={streamingStatusChanged} handleDuration={handleDuration} ref={publisherRef} />

......
      </Layout>
    </AgoraProvider>
```

this is the code of the LivePubComp :

```
const LivePublisherComponent = React.forwardRef(({ onStatusChanged, handleDuration }: props, ref: React.Ref<any>) => {
  const { client } = useAgora();
  const live = useSelector((state: StoreState) => state.lives.item);
  const token = useSelector((state: StoreState) => state.lives.token);
  const localTracks = useRef<LocalTracks>({ videoTrack: null, audioTrack: null });
  const clientRef = useRef<any>();
  let streamDurationIntervalRef = useRef<any>();
  const [tracks, setTracks] = useState<IAgoraTrack | null>(null);
  const [isStarted, setIsStarted] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const publish = async () => {
    if (!client || !live || !AGORA_APP_ID || !live?.sessionId || !live.creator) return;

    await client.join(AGORA_APP_ID, live.sessionId, token, live.creator._id);

    const [microphoneTrack, cameraTrack] = await agoraUtil.createLocalTracks({}, { encoderConfig: { bitrateMax: 1000 } });
     
    await client.publish([microphoneTrack, cameraTrack]);

    setTracks({ tracks: [microphoneTrack, cameraTrack] });
    localTracks.current = { videoTrack: cameraTrack, audioTrack: microphoneTrack };

    

    onStatusChanged(true);
    setIsStarted(true);
    streamDurationIntervalRef.current && clearInterval(streamDurationIntervalRef.current);
    streamDurationIntervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      handleDuration(clientRef.current.getRTCStats().Duration);
    }, 1000);
  };
```

Does anyone face the same issue I read the doc for supported browsers and mine is supported

this is the provider calling

```
...
<AgoraProvider config={{ mode: "live", codec: "h264", role: "host" }}>
      <Layout>
          <LivePubCom onStatusChanged={streamingStatusChanged} handleDuration={handleDuration} ref={publisherRef} />

......
      </Layout>
    </AgoraProvider>
```

this is the code of the LivePubComp :

```
const LivePublisherComponent = React.forwardRef(({ onStatusChanged, handleDuration }: props, ref: React.Ref<any>) => {
  const { client } = useAgora();
  const live = useSelector((state: StoreState) => state.lives.item);
  const token = useSelector((state: StoreState) => state.lives.token);
  const localTracks = useRef<LocalTracks>({ videoTrack: null, audioTrack: null });
  const clientRef = useRef<any>();
  let streamDurationIntervalRef = useRef<any>();
  const [tracks, setTracks] = useState<IAgoraTrack | null>(null);
  const [isStarted, setIsStarted] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const publish = async () => {
    if (!client || !live || !AGORA_APP_ID || !live?.sessionId || !live.creator) return;

    await client.join(AGORA_APP_ID, live.sessionId, token, live.creator._id);

    const [microphoneTrack, cameraTrack] = await agoraUtil.createLocalTracks({}, { encoderConfig: { bitrateMax: 1000 } });
     
    await client.publish([microphoneTrack, cameraTrack]);

    setTracks({ tracks: [microphoneTrack, cameraTrack] });
    localTracks.current = { videoTrack: cameraTrack, audioTrack: microphoneTrack };

    

    onStatusChanged(true);
    setIsStarted(true);
    streamDurationIntervalRef.current && clearInterval(streamDurationIntervalRef.current);
    streamDurationIntervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      handleDuration(clientRef.current.getRTCStats().Duration);
    }, 1000);
  };
```

Does anyone face the same issue I read the doc for supported browsers and mine is supported